Number Conversion problem (, to .) with R RDCOMClient Package
I am using R to write in Excel and then refresh another page of that same Excel using RDCOMClient.
My Excel is in german and inside Excel I have checked the option "Use system seperators" in Excel Options-> Advanced for "Decimal seperator", "Thousand seperator".
The issue is that as I refresh and save the excel via R and then reopen it, the seperators are messed up.
To change my system configurations is no option.
